# Combining multiple CSV files into one dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, read.csv

I am trying to concatenate csv files (with same headers) from folder in one df, but I get an empty list when reading the files:

```
from pathlib import Path  

path = '//Users//Directory//'
files = Path(path + "dirtest//").glob('*.csv')
```

If I print file names, I get them right:

```
for f in files:
     print(f.name)

filename1.csv
filename2.csv
filename3.csv
```

But when I try to read them and append sem into a list, it returns an empty list:

```
dfs = []
dfs = [pd.read_csv(f) for f in files]
dfs

[]
```

The next steps would be to concatenate the list into a df, but I couldn't get to it because the list is empty:

```
base_renov = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True)
```

Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 0):

`Path.glob` returns a generator. Once you print the values in the list, this exhausts the generator:

```
for f in files:
     print(f.name)
```

You should directly pass this to `read_csv`:

```
files = Path(path + "dirtest//").glob('*.csv')

base_renov = pd.concat(map(pd.read_csv, files), ignore_index=True)
```

Or, as a one-liner:

```
base_renov = pd.concat(map(pd.read_csv, Path('//Users//Directory//').glob('*.csv')), ignore_index=True)
```

If you really want to use a loop (for example if you have other operations to perform), first convert the generator to list:

```
files = list(Path(path + "dirtest//").glob('*.csv'))

for f in files:
     print(f.name)
dfs = [pd.read_csv(f) for f in files]

base_renov = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True)
```

Or, creates `dfs` in your loop:

```
files = list(Path(path + "dirtest//").glob('*.csv'))

dfs = []
for f in files:
     print(f.name)
     dfs.append(pd.read_csv(f))

base_renov = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: @XisCafe difficult to debug without a reproducible example of the data

Comment: Sorry, @mozway, the dataframe wasn't separated by the semicolons and they are all in the same column.